# How to separate fields?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to  write a script to separate fields. Output should be like this:

```
192.168.94.139  
middle of loop 

192.168.94.140  
middle of loop
```

There are two variables (servers) under $SERVER_SELECTION variable.

My code,

```bsh
for INPUT in $SERVER_SELECTION 
do 

    echo $INPUT | tr , '\n'
    echo "middle of loop "

done

echo "end of loop "
```

How can I modify this to take above output.

Comment: I have some inputs in "SERVER_SELECTION" variable those are 192.168.94.139, 192.168.94.140. When I use variable to get the output it prints as in a line. Then I used  `tr , '\n'` command to separate lines. But I want execute some commands under 192.168.94.139 and also 192.168.94.140.

Comment: put IFS=',' before "for" and remove "tr" command, this should split SERVER_SELECTION and INPUT will contains one ip at once

Comment: It works fine, then how to run some scripts by taking particular ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `IFS=','` before `for` and remove `tr` command, this should split `SERVER_SELECTION` and `INPUT` will contains one ip at once.

```
IFS=','
for INPUT in $SERVER_SELECTION 
do     
    echo $INPUT
    <path to script> $INPUT       # call other script and use INPUT as parameter
    echo "middle of loop "    
done    
echo "end of loop"
```

IFS stands for "internal field separator". It is used by the shell to determine how to do word splitting, i. e. how to recognize word boundaries.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much. Is there a alternative to `IFS` command?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly your trying to do but merely doing this:

```
echo "$INPUT"
echo "middle of loop "
```

should produce that result. Again maybe a `read` from file is what you want! Then you should do

```bsh
while read -r INPUT
do 

    echo "$INPUT"
    echo "middle of loop "

done < "$SERVER_SELECTION"

echo "end of loop "
```